# R Change date YY-MM-DD hh:mm to time since origin (Days.Seconds)

Tags: r, date, datetime, posixlt

I have a date input like this (currently as character class):

```
input=c("2013-05-08 11:20:10", "2013-05-08 11:21:09")
```

And want to have an output like this:

```
output=c(127.472338, 127.473032)
```

Which is the time since origin (2013-01-01 00:00:00) in days and seconds.

Previously, I used data in the output format and reconverted it to the input format using:

```
temp=as.POSIXlt(output*24*3600,origin='2013-01-01 00:00:00', tz="Etc/GMT+0")
```

How can I rewrite this so that I get the desired output?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXlt(input), as.POSIXlt('2013-01-01 00:00:00')))`

Answer (score 4):

Use `difftime` (or `-`):

```
> difftime(as.POSIXct(input), as.POSIXct("2013-01-01"))
Time differences in days
[1] 127.4307 127.4314
> as.POSIXct(input) - as.POSIXct("2013-01-01")
Time differences in days
[1] 127.4307 127.4314
```

Comment: You don't even need the `as.POSIXct` part: `difftime(input, "2013-01-01",units="days")` works just fine.

Comment: @nicola: while true, I'm not a particular fan of implicit conversion from character to Date/POSIXt.

Comment: And you are totally right. I just wanted to stress how easy can be to obtain some results in R.

Comment: @nicola: yes... too easy. :)

Comment: Thank you both very much :)

Comment: I just noticed that the time I get with this solution is off by one hour. However, if I use the following, I get the right results: `temp2=difftime(input, "2013-01-01 00:00:00", tz="Etc/GMT+0")`